# Bug found : Using the graph database service API over rest

Tags: neo4j

Respected Sir/ Madam,

i have created the graph whose input list has been given below. While finding the path between F and I, through H , it is going in infinite loop. I am not getting the desired path. It contains cyclic paths as well. I haven't got the answer to this from any other site. So I am posting this question here.

Code:

```
create (A:_schema_A)
create (B:_schema_B)
create (C:_schema_C)
create (D:_schema_D)
create (E:_schema_E)
create (F:_schema_F)
create (G:_schema_G)
create (H:_schema_H)
create (I:_schema_I)
create (J:_schema_J)

CREATE (A)-[:HAS]->(B)
CREATE (A)-[:HAS]->(C)
CREATE (A)-[:HAS]->(D)

CREATE (B)-[:HAS]->(D)
CREATE (B)-[:HAS]->(E)

CREATE (C)-[:HAS]->(D)
CREATE (C)-[:HAS]->(F)

CREATE (D)-[:HAS]->(E)
CREATE (D)-[:HAS]->(F)
CREATE (D)-[:HAS]->(G)

CREATE (E)-[:HAS]->(G)
CREATE (E)-[:HAS]->(H)

CREATE (F)-[:HAS]->(G)
CREATE (F)-[:HAS]->(I)

CREATE (G)-[:HAS]->(H) 
CREATE (G)-[:HAS]->(I)
CREATE (G)-[:HAS]->(J)

CREATE (H)-[:HAS]->(B)
CREATE (H)-[:HAS]->(J)

CREATE (I)-[:HAS]->(C)
CREATE (I)-[:HAS]->(J)

RETURN A;
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: If you want an answer we must have more information. Post the code (Cypher query?) which causes problems and describe the symptoms i.e. why do you think that it is going into an infinite loop. See [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the shortest path(s) starting at F, ending at I, but going through H, you can look for:

```
(a) The shortest path(s) from F to H, and
(b) The shortest path(s) from H to I.
```

By combining any path in (a) with any path in (b), you'd end up with (one of) the shortest path(s).

Here is a basic solution that finds (a) and (b):

```
MATCH (F:_schema_F),(H:_schema_H),(I:_schema_I)
RETURN allShortestPaths((F)-->(H)), allShortestPaths((H)-->(I))
```

If you had a large graph, you would need to limit the length of the paths evaluated, to avoid running for a long time (or "forever"). For instance, to limit the searched path length to 6 relationships, the above query would look like this:

```
MATCH (F:_schema_F),(H:_schema_H),(I:_schema_I)
RETURN allShortestPaths((F)-[*..6]->(H)), allShortestPaths((H)-[*..6]->(I))
```

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/?id=lx4pb) that shows the results of the latter query. (a) has only one path [with 2 relationships]. (b) has 3 paths [with 4 relationships].